# catch exception qualified by namespace

Tags: c++, exception, namespaces, try-catch

I have an exception defined like this:

```
namespace Splat {
    class MyException : public std::exception
```

and in my code I catch it like this:

```
} catch (MyException &e) {
    ....
} catch (...) {
    ....
```

The first `catch` block where I explicitly declare the exception fails to catch the exception and it is caught in second `...` wildcard block.

When I try to qualify the exception declaration with its namespace `Splat` i.e.

```
} catch (Splat::MyException &e) {
```

I get an error:

```
MyCode.cpp:123: error: expected type-specifier
MyCode.cpp:123: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
MyCode.cpp:123: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
MyCode.cpp:123 error: expected ‘{’ before ‘&’ token
MyCode.cpp:123: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
```

It seems to me that this second approach is correct as I haven't explicitly joined `Splat` into my namespace with `using namespace Splat;`.

The various examples I have reviewed suggest that including a namespace qualifier in your `catch` statement is perfectly fine ...

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Did you forget to include a necessary header perhaps? Also, the first thing shouldn't compile unless it's picking up some different type called `MyException` - is there such a thing? Bottom line, we need more information.

Comment: First thing was to determine that was okay - thanks - I'll look into getting you that additional info ...

Comment: [OT]: I think you can catch by `const` reference.

Comment: I have tried `} catch (const Splat::MyException &e) {` it gives me `expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token`

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It shouldn't be compiling like @SebastianRedl had mentioned. Please provide more details. Some actual code maybe? Something from `MyCode.cpp`

Comment: @robert Then it's not **M**, I'm afraid. Isolating the problem is an essential programming skill. You need to either keep throwing out stuff which doesn't cause the error to disappear, or start from scratch and keep adding stuff until the error appears. Very often, this process itself will give you the solution (as it will pinpoint the exact change when the problem appears/disappears).

Comment: Main concern I guess is whether there are any gotcha around typing exceptions in catch ...

Comment: Yeah I know all that angnew but if I did all that I'd probably end up solving the problem myself!

Comment: *"Yeah I know all that angnew but if I did all that I'd probably end up solving the problem myself!"* - And that's supposed to be a bad thing?

Comment: Well then this whole discussion would be redundant.

Comment: In that case, all we can tell you is that with the code you posted, `catch (MyException &e)` produces a compiler error and `catch (Splat::MyException &e)` works fine and that you have to find out why this is apparently not so on your machine. Good Stackoverflow answers require MVCEs.

Comment: Yes, thanks that was apparent about 12 comments ago ...

Comment: Yes, you can catch an `std::exception` just fine, and your own namespace is no different. Your error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The first catch block where I explicitly declare the exception fails to catch the exception and it is caught in second ... wildcard block.*

this tells me that MyException is not the same as Splat::MyException !

*MyCode.cpp:123: error: expected type-specifier*

this tells me that Splat::MyException is not a type and therefore either you use a macro MyException or MyException is a declared identifier (hiding Splat::Exception).

Another posibilty is either you use a macro Splat or Splat is a declared identifier (hiding namespace Splat ,don't know if this is possible).

Comment: Thanks for attempting an answer rather than volunteering life-coaching advice ...

Comment: I had a clashing header-file in a different module - thanks for the help!